# Should we use column used in order by clause as include column of NC INDEX

Tags: sql-server

I have created a NC index and used "LastUpdated" as a include column in index but "LastUpdated" is being used in order by clause in my query . Should we use column used in order by clause as include column of NC INDEX?

```sql
   CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IXNI__symboltab__Status_active_Symbol] 
   ON symboltab (Status,active,Symbol)
   INCLUDE (LastUpdated)

    SELECT TOP 10000 symbol,LastUpdated 
    from symboltab
    with (nolock index = IXNI__symboltab__Status_active_Symbol)
    WHERE 
        active = 1 
        AND Status = 999 --999 is default
        AND Symbol NOT LIKE '/%'
        AND Symbol NOT LIKE '%#%'
        AND Symbol NOT LIKE '!%'
    ORDER BY LastUpdated ASC
```

Comment: Note that because of the leading wildcard on the clause `Symbol NOT LIKE '%#%'` though, this is going to mean the query isn't SARGable, so it's likely the RDBMS is going to have the scan the index.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - and hints generally.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, columns listed in the `INCLUDE` clause are not part of the actual B-tree index, but rather appear only in the leaf nodes.  A consequence of this is that for your current index, the leaf nodes would generally *not* be sorted by the `LastUpdated` values.  The values would be there in the leaf nodes, but there is no guarantee of any sort.  Therefore, if you want to give your index a chance to cover all parts of your query, you should move `LastUpdated` into the actual index structure:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IXNI__symboltab__Status_active_Symbol]
    ON symboltab (Status, active, Symbol, LastUpdated);
```

Comment: A combination of three `NOT LIKE`s means that `Symbol` should probably be in the `INCLUDE` as it won't be seeked properly, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=24fef75e03e4cf75de5a1e52c25e917a

Comment: He can add AND Symbol = Symbol to enable LastUpdated to be accessed into this particular index.

Answer (score 0):

The best index for this query is actually

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IXNI__symboltab__Status_active_Symbol]
    ON symboltab (Status, active, LastUpdated) INCLUDE (Symbol);

-- alternatively

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IXNI__symboltab__Status_active_Symbol]
    ON symboltab (active, Status, LastUpdated) INCLUDE (Symbol);
```

The reason is that both `active` and `Status` have equality predicates, and can be seeked directly, therefore they should come first (in either order).

`Symbol` cannot be seeked, as it has multiple inequality predicates. Even if it had only one, it would still mess up the final sort. Therefore it must go in the `INCLUDE`, which is not part of the index key.

Finally `LastUpdated`, this means that the data is fully sorted, and does not need an extra sort.

You can see the difference in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=69c9231e448f4ff547f584ad608fc65c)

---

Side notes:

- If you get the indexing right, you do not need an index hint.
- Do *not* use `NOLOCK` unless you really know what you're doing. It's not a go-faster switch, it's a give-incorrect-results switch.

Answer (score 0):

Select Top or Fetch First is actually a filter even if order by is absent, although there is usually order by clause. The index should be:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IXNI__symboltab__Status_active_Symbol] 
   ON symboltab (LastUpdated,Status,active,Symbol)
```

And you are done searching the rows with your filters as fast as possible.
Note that if another similar query does not filter 'active' for example but does filter 'symbol' and the rest, only LastUpdated+Status part of the index will be used. So if you have more queries, study a better order of columns into the index. Put column left-wise based on their usage, the more usage the most left-wise.

Included columns now are only used for reading, not for searching. If part of the index, no included is needed. Since you select symbol,LastUpdated that are both part of the index, no included columns are needed. If you add another column like 'FirstUpdated' tomorrow and you do not filter it (just for display purpose on select list) then you can add this particular column into INCLUDE to make your query faster because when the rows are found through the index included column will help read the information from the index itself. Else it will read the found rows to get that new column.

Comment: "more usage the most right-wise" is definitely wrong, maybe you meant left-wise? Either way, pretty bad rule of thumb. It's better to look at things like equality vs inequality, ordering vs joining vs grouping columns. In your index, `Status` and `active` will not be seeked because the compiler wants to keep the `LastUpdated` sort and does not have a filter on it (SQL Server cannot do skip-scanning)

Comment: Charlieface yes right, meant left-wise, edited. The user may test all cases and tell us what index worked out better. In this query the LastUpdated is filtered when processed. Into that index it is already sorted with values, and each entry has the other 3 as well, also sorted. So the first value is searched, then the second one and so on until top X is covered. Actually it works like LastUpdated in (first value and then as many values as needed in order to reach top X).

Comment: There is no filter on `LastUpdated`, it's just scanning that in order. True you avoid a sort with this, but if that is the leading key, the rest of the columns may as well be `INCLUDE` because SQL Server cannot skip-scan, so they will not be seeked, just have a residual predicate, which can be satisfied with an `INCLUDE` column. That's why I suggested putting `Status` and `active` first

Comment: Charlieface yes I also should prefer it to work that way but... it doesn't. I just make a test. I query a table without where with a TOP 10, and, of course, it uses the unique PK as this is the default order by. It found 10 rows immediately and that's it. Then I query using a column that had a regular  index, again no where. Same story, use that index, 10 rows all the way. Then I query using 2 column existing in another index. I use first column for sorting, like in my proposition, second column for Where clause. It uses that index this time working with some 9k rows...

Comment: ... , obviously looking all the index down until satisfying 10 rows with the where clause as well.

Comment: Take this fiddle for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcfa6ea69e3afea2ca98f2dd3229ccdd Your index reads every row, whereas mine reads only the rows necessary. Check `ActualRowsRead`